# I have a scenario where I search for a name and then I need to click on correct name from search results using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I want to perform below scenario.

1) I enter a name using `sendkeys()` and then click on search button.   
2) Once I get the search results, I need to click on name which i searched for.

How do I verify and click using selenium webdriver Java.

Its `a href="/cc/name.html" target = "_blank">Name.c James/a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Saad said you could add 2 controls to be sure of the results is what you are expecting

1. Check only 1 eleent of the expected result is in the page. (Maybe you need to find inside some specific container first)
2. From that webElement compare the name

   ```
   getDriver().findElements(By.tagName("a")).size() == 1
   && getDriver().findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(0).getText().equals("Name.c James/a")
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If your search result is unique. Only 1 record will exist. If you are clicking on name, I'm assuming that it will redirect user to the next screen. So, get the relative xpath of the name and use click() .

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes It does redirect to next screen, sorry dint mention in my scenario. I want to make sure I'm clicking on right name. Thanks :)

Comment: As, I said if there is unique check then you will get unique result So, yes no doubt you will get the correct result. Further, you can get the names in an Array List and search for your name. Both approaches are quite simple.

Comment: Thanks @Saad  will try your approach and check if it works and will update

Comment: Thanks @Cralfaro will update once I try your approach . Thanks  for your help